# Resolving package conflict

Tags: java, package

Suppose we have a package called `com.example1` containing a `Hello` class (along with other classes).

Then we have another package `com.example2` also containing a `Hello` class (obviously with different behaviour).

Now let's suppose we need every class in com.example1 and the Hello class in com.example2

```
import com.example1.*;
import com.example2.Hello;
```

Which one gets called in this case?

```
Hello hello = new Hello();
```

Or does this give a compile error?

This is just a theoretical question out of curiosity.

Since packages were created to avoid naming conflict, what happens when two packages contain two classes with the same name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will give a compile error. You have to explicitly name the class - `com.example2.Hello hello = new com.example2.Hello();`

Comment: @klez Yeah, but you can leave the imports for clarity - just to be visible from where classes are imported at the top of the `java` file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of leaving it to chance, it would be best to be explicit in your declarations. It is a compile error.

A similar clash often happens with `java.util.List` and `java.awt.List`. If you are explicit, there is no confusion.

Comment: The java.awt.List collision has frustrated me to the point of removing it from my local development JRE.

Answer (score 0):

It will not give a compiler error as stated by other users. It will use com.example2.Hello. This is because explicit import (com.example2.Hello) will always have **precedence** over * import (com.example1.*).