# Example of using Java Packages

Tags: java, package

I'm playing around with Java.

Consider I am writing a class named:
`AA.java` under package name `SoUnique`.
And my friend comes with a package name `AnotherUniqueName` which includes a file name `AA.java`.

How can I use his methods in his package? Does my example make sense at all? Should I import anything? How does packaging help to avoid conflicting names?

Comment: You can import it, use full name.

Comment: You might want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/

Comment: You have to explicitly name the class. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501514/resolving-package-conflict).

Comment: You should use always lowCase for packages names (it's a global convention)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use fully qualified package name (assuming it has myfun method) like:

```
AnotherUniqueName.AA.myfun();
```

Comment: And assuming `myfun` is static :)

Comment: So, No way to use import at top of the source file?

Comment: @Meysam You can import on class like `import SoUnique.AA` and use it. But if you need class `AA` from `AnotherUniqueName` you must refer to it by FQN `AnotherUniqueName.AA`

Comment: @talex My problem is with those articles on web that say, packages help to avoid class name collision. But my packages don't help, I think. And I'm left with using full qualified package name.

Comment: @Meysam Yes, because without packages, it would not be possible at all to have two classes named `AA` - there would be no way to let the compiler know which `AA` you mean. With packages you can use the fully-qualified names to keep them apart.

Comment: @Meysam It help avoid collision in sense that you can have two class with same name. If there was no packages you simply can't refer to specific class at all. With packages you can (of course you need FQN)

Comment: @Jesper So if I want to have class named Scanner and use the Java's Scanner class capabilities, I'm not allowed to use import statement and have to use full name. Am I right?

Comment: @Meysam You could then import one of the two and use the short name; for the other one you would have to use the full name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a non  static method you can create object and call your method.

```
AnotherUniqueName.AA obj=new AnotherUniqueName.AA();
obj.yourMethod();
```